# After installing a new jdk (in IntelliJ IDEA), I get an error that class java.lang.Object.class was not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After installing the new jdk (openjdk-20.0.2) in my Idea. I try to run the test and get the error.

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Exception while looking for class java.lang.Object: java.io.IOException: Couldn't find: java.lang.Object.class`

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgeXF.png)
[Messages as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDAUK.png)

Info about IDE:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2 (Community Edition)

What can I do to fix the error in the console?

It didn't help:

- Check Project Structure (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Shift+s</kbd>)
- Reset invalidate caches
- mvn clean test
- Restart PC
- Google

Comment: Does this work outside your IDE? And are you using pure Java? (no Kotlin, Groovy, etc)

Comment: what does `javac --version` shows?

Comment: This works on a build in jenkens. The problem is local.
javac --version
javac 20.0.2

Comment: Try to delete added JDKs from `File | Project Structure | SDKs` save settings, and re-add JDK from scratch as per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#jdk

Answer (score 0):

When I had this it was because I had updated IntelliJ IDEA. It didn't seem to like SDKs/JDKs I'd imported using the old version, so I needed to remove them and then add them again using the new version.